# How do I add multiplayer in to my unity game?

Tags: unity

I made a 2d game for phones where screen is divided in two parts. I have made game for local multiplayer. Upper half player1 and lower half player2.
What do I need to do to make that upper half multiplayer so you can play with your friends or random people of internet.
What is the way to go about it?

Answer (score -1):

##### Getting your game working and networked

If you're not very familiar with coding or network concepts, I would use a package like [PUN](https://www.photonengine.com/pun) and just follow one of their introductory tutorials.

##### Learning about networking

If you're interested in networking itself, then I would familiarize myself with the basics of how internet functions, and some of its common protocols: [here's a tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XaGXPObx2Gs&list=PLowKtXNTBypH19whXTVoG3oKSuOcw_XeW). After that, I would learn about game specific architectures, how do different genres handle multiplayer? How do FPSs, RTSs, MMOs or Collectible Card Games strategies differ and why? I would implement some simple networked games with lowerish-level APIs (probably System.Net.Socket in .NET if you want cross platform).

Comment: I am kind of done with the game. Its possible to integrate multiplayer now? Making the player 2 of game as a multiplayer

Comment: generally it's pretty hard to network a game after the game is done. Of course you can do it, but often it takes a huge rewrite of the code. I would try following a beginner multiplayer tutorial first for a couple days, and you'll get a better understanding of what it would take for your game.

Comment: Although the answer is probably what they need to be told, it does not answer the question.

Comment: That's fair. I think "What is the way to go about it?" is a pretty general question though that could reasonably involve methodology to learn about the problem.